# VMware Workstation Ubuntu 18.10 Full Screen Problem

Tags: 18.10

I upgraded my VMware Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10. After the upgrade it was working fine until I shutdown and restarted the VM, and now it won't display in full screen.

I followed by installing a fresh copy of 18.10 and at first it was working fine right after install and after reboot the same thing happened.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ran into the same issue on a fresh install of 18.10 on VMWare 15.01. If I manually restarted open-vm-tools after I logged in, everything worked. I tried to reinstall VMWare tools, it didn't help. This did fix it:

Edit this file using your preferred editing tool

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/open-vm-tools.service
```

Add these lines to the end of the "Unit" section

```
Requires=graphical.target
After=graphical.target
```

Save the file and the next time you restart you should be good to go.

You can apply the changes immediately without restarting by running

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service open-vm-tools restart
```

Comment: Worked for me as well for Ubuntu 18.04 after some upgrade.

Comment: Works for me. Win10 + VMware WS 15 Player + ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64

Answer (score 1):

Create a text file with .sh extension. For example `setscreen.sh`

Insert the following text and save.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080
```

Run this .sh file as an executable. Screen should go to 1920x1080.

Use "startup applications" to launch the file at startup.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings > display > specify monitor settings.Then choose the right resolution for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/303

Requires an edit to Unit section of open-vm-tools

After=graphical.target

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `sudo service open-vm-tools restart` as command in "Startup Applications", to make it run after system starts.

Answer (score 0):

Delaying the service open-vm-tools to start after the display manager and it seems to work.

~$ sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/open-vm-tools.service

Add under [Unit] the following line:

After=display-manager.service

Reference https://communities.vmware.com/thread/576221

Save the file and reboot. The screen should be able to fit as needed.